# Creating aggregated JSON objects

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

My database looks like this:

Raw Table Data :

[image]

The Result returned :

[image]

from the query below :

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY stokkodu ) AS RowNum,
       stokkodu,
       adi,
       beden,
       renk,
       kalan,
       afiyat
  FROM (SELECT stokkodu, adi, afiyat, renk, SUM(kalan) AS kalan, beden
          FROM [viabase].[dbo].[Q_KALANS]
         GROUP BY stokkodu, adi, afiyat, renk, beden) AS products
```

Now I need to get the sizes of the products grouped under separate color nodes to fetch from the DB to present to the client site as in the JSON Format like this :

[image]

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: `MERGE` has a specific meaning in SQL; ity an operator that can be used to `INSERT`,  `UPDATE` and `DELETE` against an object in a single statement. What you seem to want here is some form of malformed JSON.

Comment: I don't know the terms in SQL this is why I am asking so all I want is to get data like I mentioned in post.

Comment: Hi whitehead421 . Unfortunately, the summed up amounts are inconsistent with the row data.

Comment: Yes, they are. It is only visualization of what I want to get in return as JSON format.

Comment: Please don't use images for data, code or errors. Use formatted text.

Comment: Sample data and expected results as text are a must. We cannot copy and paste any of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have the `JSON_AGG` function, which would have made this easier. Instead we need to hack it with a combination of `STRING_AGG` to aggregate, `STRING_ESCAPE` to correctly escape the values, and `JSON_QUERY` to prevent double-escaping.

You also need to get the base `adi` value. I've tried to do that with `REPLACE` and `TRIM` but cannot test due to lack of proper sample data.

```sql
WITH L1 AS (
  SELECT
    adi = TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(qk.adi, qk.renk, ''), qk.beden, '')),
    qk.renk,
    qk.beden,
    SUM(qk.kalan) AS kalan
  FROM dbo.Q_KALANS qk
  GROUP BY
    qk.adi,
    qk.renk,
    qk.beden
),
L2 AS (
  SELECT
    qk.adi,
    qk.renk,
    json = '{' + STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', STRING_ESCAPE(qk.beden, 'json'), '":', SUM(kalan)), ',') + '}'
  FROM L1 qk
  GROUP BY
    qk.adi,
    qk.renk
)
SELECT
    qk.adi,
    STOCK = JSON_QUERY('{' + STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', STRING_ESCAPE(qk.renk, 'json'), '":', qk.json), ',') + '}')
FROM L2 qk
GROUP BY
    qk.adi
FOR JSON PATH;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8c98b5f729a00753eb72d9295a16a028)

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked me with few edits.